# Answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers

I posted a short -- but not too short -- answer to [Narrow streets behind houses](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/226169/narrow-streets-behind-houses) but it almost instantly disappeared.

Can you tell me why?

Answer (score 3):

I don’t see an answer from you on that post. It looks like you posted your answer on a different question here: [What is this large mammal with antlers called: a moose or an elk?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/130496/36187)

A user flagged it and I have deleted it. You’re welcome to repost it under the correct question. However, if you could provide a few more details, like where it’s used or a dictionary entry, that would be helpful.

Comment: Well that's darned embarrassing!

Comment: @RonJohn - Antlers, allies – it's an easy mistake to make. Don't be too hard on yourself. :-) By the way, I took the liberty to add a substantiating example to your answer, in accordance with Em's advice here.  I hope you don't mind.